# OPENSSL Import Error executing sh script on HPC Cluster

Tags: shell, openssl, operating-system, slurm

Trying to run a pipeline in Snakemake and OPENSSL is returning an error during the execution of a bash script function (which executes one of the custom commands in the pipeline).

I have been having a lot of issues with things like GCC versions, libstdc++6, and similar base-system things in various conda environments and such. I get different results sometimes when I run things in command-line vs. in a bash script, etc.

My colleague suggested I try different versions of GCC, which I have done, but it has not helped.

I'm not really sure how to even begin debugging this. Most of the solutions I've found online have required sudo permissions, which I do not have because I am a user on a cluster, not the administrator.

Could someone point me to what might generally be wrong here, or how I can start fixing this issue?

Thank you!

Tried: isolating problematic bash script (custom function, works on other systems) in a .sh script. Running using sbatch slurm on large cluster.

Expected: script to output normally.

What resulted: crash during the import of another python module:

ImportError: /lib64/libldap.so.2: undefined symbol: EVP_md2, version OPENSSL_3.0.0

What I've tried: loading 4 different versions of GCC, re-loading terminal.

All other solutions I've found either require sudo permissions, or are the result of a user messing with OPENSSL or Rocky Linux, neither of which I've touched.